# How can I embed an href for .NET MVC within a jQuery database column?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I am using jQuery Datatable with ajax to build a datatable. In the last column I want to add an edit link to take the user to another page to edit the data. So I want to use something link this

```
<a href="/Vendors/Edit/53">Edit</a>
```

The end result should look like

```
ID Name LastUpdUser LastUpdDate Edit
```

where `Edit` is `/Edit/IDNumber`.

My current code is

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Vendors/GetAllVendors',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        $('#datatable').dataTable({
            data: data,
            columns: [
                { 'data': 'ID' },
                { 'data': 'Name' },
                { 'data': 'LastUpdUser' },
                { 'data': 'LastUpdDate' },
                {
                    'data': 'ID',
                    'render': function (data) {
                        return '<a href="/Vendors/Edit/"' + data + '">Edit</a>';
                    }
                }
            ]
        })

    },
```

which is getting me close but the url is just 
`/Edit/`

Comment: Thanks for the edits Mike. You cleaned it up a lot. However, Edit is a MVC URL so it really should look like "http://localhost/Vendors/Edit/IDNumber",if you hover over the Edit Link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO, I have just started with DataTables and came across this problem. I had luckily followed a little tutorial and seen his buttons working.

```
{
    "data": "ID",
    "render": function (ID)
    {
        return '<a class="btn-xs btn-primary glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt" 
        href=/Vendors/Edit/' + ID +'></a>';
    }
}
```

If you notice the href has no quotes around it, job sorted and should be working for you, mine is returning edit as a bootstrap styled button.

With out styling just as you have listed it.

```
{
    "data": "ID",
    "render": function (ID)
    {
        return '<a href=/Vendors/Edit/' + ID +'></a>';
    }
}
```

I honestly can not say why the quotes throws it out, but I am playing with everything learning Datatables with MVC and ServerSide processing.

Comment: Andy, this worked! Thank you very much. I tried to upvote but I don't have enough rep yet :(.  BTW:  Which tutorials are you watching?

Comment: @TomHarder I have tried so many datatables and found all to be lacking or limit you at some vital point. It was whilst switching to Server Side processing from my previous Datatable I came across [Link]http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1118363/GridView-with-Server-Side-Filtering-Sorting-and-Pa[Link] This got me stuck into DataTables and I have found it excellent. I am having to figure out a lot myself i.e. formatting etc but post on SO and you will get help/ Answers.

Comment: I should also add, I did find last night the one and it might be the killer problem for me using DataTables. The ability to add columns based on User Role. I will be posting this up on SO shortly when I get a chance to phrase the question well.

Answer (score 0):

try to pass null data parameter, and use row instead

like this:

```
{
    data: null,
    render: function ( data, type, row ) {
        return '<a href="/Vendors/Edit/"' + row.ID + '">Edit</a>';
    }
}
```

Comment: RizkiDPrast. Tried this but result was the same. However, when I step through with VS, type and row are not defined, data holds all the rows.  Should I be specifying something for type and row? Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: what about your first column "ID". was it returning correct ID?

Comment: Yes the first column "ID" was the record ID's from the database. And they were showing up okay. I could try some javascript and manually put the href together, but that seems too hard. I just think understanding how these columns works seems like the right idea.

Comment: its weird. I haven't completely read datatable documentation but seems like you dont have to specifying something for type and row to make it accessible. May be it won't allow you to set multiple column with same data. to test that perhaps, try to remove your first ID column

Comment: The issue is the double quotes around the href, as Andy Donegan pointed out.  Eliminate the double quotes and this will work also. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look [Here](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) i think u need to change to **columnDefs**

```
$('#example').dataTable({
    "columnDefs": [{            
        "data": null,
        "render": function(data, type, full, meta) {
             return '<a href=/Vendors/Edit/' + full.ID +'></a>';
        }
    }]
});
```